# Why is the tail recursive version of factorial function so slow in Python?

Tags: python, performance, recursion, tail-recursion

I am trying to compare the running time of factorial functions of different implementations. However, I found that the tail-recursive version of the factorial function is much slower than the iterative version and non-tail-recursive version and I can't figure out an explanation for this.
Here is my code implementation. I am using Python 3.7.4 to test the code.

```
import sys
from line_profiler import LineProfiler
sys.setrecursionlimit(20000)


def fact_iter(n):
    """Return the factorial of n, using iteration"""
    product = 1
    for i in range(2, n + 1):
        product *= i
    return product


def fact_non_tail_recur(n):
    """Return the factorial of n, using non-tail recursion"""
    if n == 1:
        return 1
    product = n * fact_non_tail_recur(n - 1)
    return product


def fact_tail_recur(n, product=1):
    """Return the factorial of n, using tail recursion"""
    if n == 1:
        return product
    product *= n
    return fact_tail_recur(n - 1, product)


def fact_tail_recur_2(n, i=1, product=1):
    if i == n:
        return product * i
    product *= i
    return fact_tail_recur_2(n, i+1, product)


def profile(f):
    lp = LineProfiler()
    lp_wrapper = lp(f)
    lp_wrapper(10000)
    lp.print_stats()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    profile(fact_iter)
    profile(fact_non_tail_recur)
    profile(fact_tail_recur)
    profile(fact_tail_recur_2)
```

And here is the running time profile of the functions.

```
Timer unit: 1e-06 s

Total time: 0.040521 s
File: fact.py
Function: fact_iter at line 6

Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
     6                                           def fact_iter(n):
     7                                               """Return the factorial of n, using iteration"""
     8         1          2.0      2.0      0.0      product = 1
     9     10000      13513.0      1.4     33.3      for i in range(2, n + 1):
    10      9999      27005.0      2.7     66.6          product *= i
    11         1          1.0      1.0      0.0      return product

Timer unit: 1e-06 s

Total time: 0.042846 s
File: fact.py
Function: fact_non_tail_recur at line 14

Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
    14                                           def fact_non_tail_recur(n):
    15                                               """Return the factorial of n, using non-tail recursion"""
    16     10000      13389.0      1.3     31.2      if n == 1:
    17         1          2.0      2.0      0.0          return 1
    18      9999      16481.0      1.6     38.5      product = n * fact_non_tail_recur(n - 1)
    19      9999      12974.0      1.3     30.3      return product

Timer unit: 1e-06 s

Total time: 0.085538 s
File: fact.py
Function: fact_tail_recur at line 22

Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
    22                                           def fact_tail_recur(n, product=1):
    23                                               """Return the factorial of n, using tail recursion"""
    24     10000      13812.0      1.4     16.1      if n == 1:
    25         1          2.0      2.0      0.0          return product
    26      9999      55390.0      5.5     64.8      product *= n
    27      9999      16334.0      1.6     19.1      return fact_tail_recur(n - 1, product)

Timer unit: 1e-06 s

Total time: 0.07916 s
File: fact.py
Function: fact_tail_recur_2 at line 30

Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
    30                                           def fact_tail_recur_2(n, i=1, product=1):
    31     10000      13521.0      1.4     17.1      if i == n:
    32         1         12.0     12.0      0.0          return product * i
    33      9999      49390.0      4.9     62.4      product *= i
    34      9999      16237.0      1.6     20.5      return fact_tail_recur_2(n, i+1, product)
```

The graph of running time measured by timeit

[image: Running time measured by timeit]

Comment: FWIW, Python does not have TCO.

Comment: What happens if you remove the `=1` from `product=1`?

Comment: Yes indeed, so I was hoping the running time of tail-recursion would be close to the non-tail-recursion. It can't explain the measurable running time difference between them.

Comment: Just curious, are you looking for the fastest way to get a factorial or an explanation of what’s going on “behind the scenes” of your different methods?  It’s a good and interesting question.

Comment: @MateenUlhaq There is no big difference.

Comment: @Ethan I'm not trying to find the fastest way, just curious about the reason.

Comment: I do not know much about profiling Python code, but the main difference in the execution conditions I can see in these functions is passing the accumulated `product` as a parameter. This will be quite a big value, so I suspect it may have some impact on the overall performance. Did you try to move it outside the parameter list, e.g. to some external variable? Both tail-recursive routines modify the `product` value at one point only, on the way down the recursion, and then just copy it through all returns, so it should be possible to avoid storing it on the stack...

Comment: @CiaPan Thank you, making `product` a global variable indeed can speed it up. But why? Aren't Python functions Pass by object reference? So I though extra parameters wound't be a big overhead.

Comment: Try to estimate how big those objects are. The last one is a number `10000!` which is about 35.7 thousand decimal digits (according to [this](http://gimbo.org.uk/texts/ten_thousand_factorial.txt) page), which is about 118.4 thousand binary digits, which makes about 14.8 thousand bytes – allocated and managed just for the final result. For `1000!` we get about 1 KB and for `500!` – about 0.4 KB. This makes 10000 allocations for total well above 100 KBytes just for intermediate, temporary single-use data. Passing by reference doesn't necessary reduce the amount of allocations.